# Google OAuth - Invalid grant: account not found error only in Docker

Tags: python, google-oauth, gspread

I have a very simple piece of code written in python. It works without any issue while running locally.

```py
import gspread 
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from os import environ as env

scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

keyfile_dict = {"type": "service_account",
                "project_id": env["GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID"],
                "private_key_id": env["GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY_ID"],
                "private_key": env["GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY"],
                "client_email": env["GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL"],
                "client_id": env["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"],
                "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
                "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
                "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
                "client_x509_cert_url": env["GOOGLE_CLIENT_X509_CERT_URL"]
            }
            
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(keyfile_dict, scopes=scopes)
conn = gspread.authorize(credentials) 

spreadsheet = conn.open_by_key('sheet_name')
```

But when I built a docker image and then run it, I get the following error at `conn.open_by_key`.

```
'invalid_grant: Invalid grant: account not found', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Invalid grant: account not found'}
```

The error is only while running it via the docker. I ran using both the commands, but still no luck.

`docker run -d -p 3003:3004 -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro <image_name>`

and

`docker run -d -p 3003:3004 <image_name>`

I looked wherever I could, and I was told that docker clock vs host clock. I really do not know how to fix this. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the other parameters not being read from the env variables. Once that is fixed, the problem got resolved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).